# Javascript | Creating a popup that triggers just before the page is closed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have already created a popup overlay and currently have it set to when you click a button. However, I want it so that when you have initially scrolled down on the website and then go to move your cursor towards the top of the page (towards the navigation for example) then the popup window will appear.

Javascript

```
// Initialize Variables
var closePopup = document.getElementById("popupclose");
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
var button = document.getElementById("button");
// Close Popup Event
closePopup.onclick = function() {
    overlay.style.display = 'none';
    popup.style.display = 'none';
};
// Show Overlay and Popup
button.onclick = function() {
    overlay.style.display = 'block';
    popup.style.display = 'block';
}
```

I have created a JSFiddle with all my current code.
https://jsfiddle.net/1ud9crou/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `jQuery`, you could do:

```
var isOnTop = false;
$(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    mouseIsOnTop = e.pageY < 20;
    if (mouseIsOnTop) {
        button.onclick();
    }
});
```

Otherwise, with bare Javascript (if you need IE support):

```
(function() {
    document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
        var dot, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;

        event = event || window.event;

        // if pageX/Y aren't available and clientX/Y are, calculate pageX/Y
        if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
            eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
            doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
            body = eventDoc.body;
            event.pageX = event.clientX +
              (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
              (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
            event.pageY = event.clientY +
              (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
              (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
        }

        mouseIsOnTop = event.pageY < 20;
        if (mouseIsOnTop) {
            button.onclick();
        }
    }
})();
```

**UPDATE**: to detect if user scrolled from top:

```
var userDidScrollABit = false;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var body = document.body;
    var document = document.documentElement;
    document = (document.clientHeight) ? document : body;
    if (document.scrollTop > 20) {
        userDidScrollABit = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Would this JS be placed at the end of my current code or is it all instead of the original? Thanks for the help.

Comment: At the end of your code... Or better, at the top (global callbacks are usually placed on top, but this is a matter of taste... :)

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you very much :) One final question, is there a line of JS that is able to tell whether the user has scrolled down the page or not?

I want the popup to only show when they have scrolled down a bit on the site.